# CMake/GCC "unrecognized option" on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake

I'm trying to create a project as a shared library in OS X using CMake 2.8 and gcc 4.6 (from macports). When CMake gets to the point of linking my library into a .dylib, I get the following error from gcc:

```
g++   -dynamiclib -headerpad_max_install_names -o libmycoollibrary.dylib etc...
g++: error: unrecognized option '-h'
make[2]: *** [libnrtCore.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/nrtCore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This -headerpad_max_install_names seems to be the problem, but I've never seen it before. Does anyone know how to either get CMake to not include this option, or to get GCC to accept this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-build cmake to fix this -- it's apparently generating code for the XCode / Darwin version of g++ (a special version of 4.2), which accepts a number of non-standard linker flags.

Just change the Modules/Platform/Darwin*.cmake files and re-build. The culprit lines look like this:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use gcc 4.6 because I need support for the very latest C++0x features.

Comment: Looks like you will have to rebuild cmake; the file to change is Darwin.cmake. The culprit line is

SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names")

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Would you mind editing your answer to reflect your comment so that I can accept it? Also please note that just changing Darwin.cmake didn't work - I had to change all of the Modules/Platform/Darwin* files to get it to work.